# How to calculate number of assets with over 10000 vulnerabilities each

Tags: qliksense

I've got this script that is represented in a bar graph:

```
Count({$< MitigationType = {'Security Update'}, [VulnScanDate]={'$(=MaxString(VulnScanDate))'}>}distinct[Asset_Name])
```

This calculates and displays the number of vulnerabilities that occur the most. 
I want to show in a KPI the number of unique vulnerabilities that occur over 10000 times in a scan.

In a bar graph, the Dimension is Vulnerability and the Measure is the long script mentioned above.

```
Count({$< MitigationType = {'Security Update'}, [VulnScanDate]={'$(=MaxString(VulnScanDate))'}>}distinct[Asset_Name])
```

The expected result should be 5 (based on current data set) on a KPI tile, but I am not getting any value in the KPI. The formula is designed for bar graph where it has Dimension and Measure properties.

Answer (score 0):

Put the TOTAL parameter in your MaxString expression:

```
Count({$< MitigationType = {'Security Update'}, [VulnScanDate]={'$(=MaxString(TOTAL VulnScanDate))'}>}distinct[Asset_Name])
```

cordially.